# How to use IIS on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, website, iis

I wanted to create a website where you can download my apps and I wanted to use wordpress or weebly but I want to be in full control of my website, like even the 404 webpages have to be deigned by me.
so after googling it, I found that you can Internet Information Services to host a website on windows 10, so I went to optional windows features and I turned it on from there.
when creating a website, I specified the location of accessing files to be in D:\website\res

but then it says
`The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.`

I have no idea what this is, please help me guys I really the website.
note: it gives this message in any location.
and I even enabled permissions for the IIS accounts.

Comment: Literally any major web server can do that. You probably don't want to host your website on your own PC.

Comment: look at the site setting "Physical credentials", and  if you site uses an application pool, look at the identity used by it. if the app pool user does not have access to the directory grant it. if its "AppPoolIdentity" then the user in question is `IIS AppPool\<AppPoolName>`. if the siet does not use an app pool, look in advanced settings and set the physical access credentials to a user on the system that has access to the directory. you should probably create a local user for that purpose.

Comment: Not using the default website causes probably a permissions problem. See [What, exactly, is “Default Website”?](https://superuser.com/questions/825580/what-exactly-is-default-website)

Comment: @harrymc I did try using the Default website as well but it still gives me the permission error...

Answer (score 1):

This is a by-design "benign" warning simply telling us a verification
has been deferred to runtime. This can be ignored in most cases
(if you are sure that the accessing users will have access permissions).

With pass-through authentication, it uses the authenticated user. That will either be the anonymous user, the application pool identity, or the passed credentials if using basic or integrated authorization.

Most likely the reason for the message is that you have disabled
Anonymous access and chosen instead Integrated Windows authentication.
As the user's credentials cannot be known in advance, IIS is warning you
that they might be insufficient to access the resource.
IIS cannot know in advance which user account will access the site.

Comment: okay, thanks for the solution! I have one more doubt, even when i click start website or type local host in chrome it says, 'check if theres a typo in . . .' and local host refused to connect respectively. how do I fix this ?

Comment: I would need more information, perhaps with screenshots. I think a new post will be better.